# Will my supervisor be contacted by a conference if my submission is rejected or requires revison?

Tags: peer-review, conference, email, supervision, journal-workflow

I submitted my paper to conference proceedings and still waiting to get the feedback within 2 months. When I uploaded the paper they asked me to fill the name and email for each co-author in the paper. So I did as they ask and I noticed that they sent an email to all mentioned authors (including the office of my professor and his secretary) that the paper is received and still under review.

What I want to ask is If the paper rejected or sent back to major reviews will my professor get an email from them as I will get?

Comment: what is your field? Did you use any platform like EasyChair? If yes, then _all_ the authors are notified.

Comment: @PsySp field of computer science, conference name is WI2017 that will be held il Leipzig Germany. https://wi-lab.com/cyberchair/2017/wi17/scripts/submitform.php

Comment: Ok, I checked it and this system is unknown to me (it's not standard). What can I offer it's a _guess_ and that is that everybody will be informed.

Comment: The system is cyberchair, and I've seen it before in another conference. In my case, I received the notification e-mail even though I was not the submitting author.

Comment: Your supervisor's secretary is an author? That's very egalitarian of you!

Comment: What exactly is OP worrying about?

Answer (score 7):

Some conference systems do, and some systems don't. If the system contacted all authors upon submission, one could speculate that it will also do this when a decision on the paper has been made. But it really depends on the system, and as there are so many, it's hard to predict.

But I'm going to add that it shouldn't matter: Whatever the outcome, you will have to tell your coauthors one way or the other. If they learn it from an automated email, then that is as good as if you sent them a personal email.